# How to get fbid, name, email from facebook using latest php SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Need help.

how to get facebook email on sign in using php sdk

Comment: please do some research, programming and testing before asking.

Comment: i have already do that and get the code from here.

https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk

use this code but not get email. we get id and name of facebook user

Comment: alright, now i get the question. it gets asked a LOT, but usually in a more detailed way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

You have to specify the fields you want to get, else you will only get ID and name. For example:

```
/me?fields=name,email
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Include java script FB SDK:

   `<script>(function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=PLACE_YOUR_FB_APP_ID";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`
2. Initiate link to connect with Facebook:

   `<script>function FBLogin(){`

   ```
      FB.login(function(response){

        if(response.authResponse){

           var USERID  =   response.authResponse.userID;

           FB.api('/me', function(userinfo){
               jQuery.ajax({

               type:"POST",

               url: "ajax_fb_login.php",

               data:  "userinfo="+userinfo,

               success: function(html){

               }
             });
           });
           } 
       }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
   }</script>
   ```
3. Retrieve the facebook data in your php file:

   $fbid        =   $_REQUEST['userinfo']['id'];
       $email      =   $_REQUEST['userinfo']['email'];
       $first_name =   $_REQUEST['userinfo']['first_name'];
       $last_name  =   $_REQUEST['userinfo']['last_name'];
       $fb_name    =   $_REQUEST['userinfo']['name'];

Comment: he specifically said "using the php sdk", this does not really answer the question - even though it´s way too broad and should be closed.

Comment: u have demo for that.

Comment: Why don't you give a try in google?
Live Demo and downloadable script for you:
http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/login-with-facebook-and-twitter.html
:)

Comment: First try understanding this one. (They provided complete code using OAuth protocol)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login
This one narrates for beginners.
http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/

Hope you got enough information!